# Application inside another application in iOS

Tags: ios

How do you import or display an application inside another application? 
It is like, it will be a part of the app where you can use it's functionalities. Maybe in full screen or not in full screen. My thoughts are these are web based and is being opened in a UIWebView to use the functionalities. 
Extensions? It's more like "piggybacking".

Here's an example: 
https://hub.united.com/en-us/news/web/pages/uber-on-the-united-app.aspx

Comment: Either you use `UIWebView` (if they have a functional website), or what I think, is that they have an API/SDK (with WebService) that allow you to use some functionalities, like FaceBook one for example, etc.

Comment: Yes, UIWebView. API/SDK hmm can be, but it should popup or something right? In the picture it's more like an item or is in the cell and is using the other app's graphics too.

Comment: What is so special about that app? What functionality are you talking about exactly?

Comment: Well, FaceBook API gives a login sample VC that you can customise. So Uber may have given them some graphics elements (images, etc.). They may have also a special partenership.

Comment: @Popeye Where United App can use Uber's UI and functionalities inside it.

Comment: The uber app will probably have a URL Scheme which the united hub searches for using `canOpenUrl:` and if it returns false forwards them to the website instead. It's pretty simple, the united app doesn't have any of the uber apps functionality inside it at all. Have a look for custom URL Schemes and you will get a better undertanding

Comment: @Popeye that was my first impression too. Thanks! I was thinking there might be another way or a more complex way of having one. Larme's can be possible too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post an answer regrouping my answer and also @Popeye one that seems valid too.

There may be a few ways to do it, each ones of them may act differently.

- The other app offers a public SDK/API/WebServices
  As an example, I'll take FaceBook API, that allow you to login giving you a `UIViewController` (that you can customise), and allowing you to ask for some data through their WebServices (like who are the friends, etc.). You're still inside your app.
- The other app offers you a private SDK/API/WebServices
  Same as the other one, but it more like a parternship. You're still inside your app.
- URL Schemes
  The other app gives you a few way to interact with it. They check if the app is installed, and launch it with some parameters, or if not, they may redirect it to the app in the Store, their website, etc. [More info about URL Schemes from Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html). You have to check their documentaion to know how to interact with it.

Comment: +1 though the way I think that the united hub app works is with URL Schemes as that makes the most sense based on the description of the app. I'd probably say the other two are the extreme cases but I see no reason for implementing them.